# CVS command to get the current revision number of file

Tags: cvs

I need a simple way to get the revision of file using cvs. I can get it using the `CVS/Entries` file. It is not safe and I think there must be another way. `cvs log` prints too much than I need. How can I get only the revision number of some file using cvs commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cvs log -h` shows just the header information. To get just the version, it's easy enough to filter that through sed, awk, or Perl.

This gives you the version in the repository. If you want the version of the checked-out file, you can use `ident` (part of RCS) -- but only if you've included the proper keywords in the file. (This doesn't work well for binaries.)

For example, if you add something like the following to your file before checking it in:

```
# $Id:$
# $Source:$
```

then `ident foo.txt` will print something like this:

```
foo.txt:
     $Id: foo.txt,v 1.3 2011/10/17 22:49:45 kst Exp $
     $Source: /path/to/repo/sandbox/foo.txt,v $
```

There are a number of other keywords you can use. See the [Keyword substitution](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_12.html) section of the CVS manual for details.

This can go wrong in various ways; for example, if you edit the file after checking it out, the expanded keywords won't necessarily reflect anything meaningful. You can use `cvs diff` to determine whether a file has been modified after checkout.

As I mentioned, if you try to do this with a binary file, it can corrupt the file (which is why if you tell CVS that a file is binary, it won't do keyword substitution).

The `ident` command is part of RCS, not CVS, so you'll have to install RCS on your system if it's not already there. (It would have made sense to have a `cvs ident` command; I'm not sure why it's not there.)

More "modern" source control systems tend not to provide this facility.

Comment: Yes I need the version of my checked-out file. Can you provide example how to use `ident`

Comment: Modern version control systems don't provide this facility because the general consensus is that it's a Bad Idea to redundantly store versioning information in your source code.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster: And yet it can actually be a useful feature (I've certainly found it so).

Comment: Come on! Take a chance and join the 21st century!